# linking functions from a userform to a sub function

Tags: excel, vba

i have created a userform to solve numerical ODEs with initial value problem ie the Euler,Runge-kutta and the rest [the userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1b1t.png)

i want to type the function at where the f(x,y) is, that will link to the function module and then when a code to solve when i click on solve.

i have tried doing all i can and a little bit of research but i still cant find anything.

i would be glad to get some help from here

Comment: Please show what you have tried already, be specific

Comment: This doesn't look right. The function should be in the code - not to be provided by the user. The user should enter parameters only. When you click 'Solve' the result should be issued somewhere. Normally that would be in the form itself. Then the user can accept the result and write it to the worksheet (closing the form at the same time) or change the parameters for another result.